# Synchronizing data output stream

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm having a problem where I have a class that gets instantiated upon a connection to server.

The method I'm having trouble with in the class looks like so:

```
public void sendData(byte[] dataToSend) throws IOException {
    sendLock.lock();

    int dataLength = dataToSend.length;
    dout.writeInt(dataLength);
    dout.write(dataToSend, 0, dataLength);
    dout.flush();

    sendLock.unlock();
}
```

Where `sendLock` is a `ReentrantLock` and `dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());`. This will work fine with a limited number of threads, but if I have a large number of threads calling this method concurrently I get a deadlock and the program just stops.

Is there any reason a deadlock would be happening here? It doesn't make sense to me, as I've removed all other locks to rule them out and I'm down to this one. Is there anyway the flush could cause things to hang or something? It just seems like at some point it never releases the lock and I'm not sure why.

If I remove the lock I get socket errors because one thread may change the dataLength before another has a chance to write, etc. But the deadlock no longer occurs.

As a reference, here's what the run method of the Receive end looks like:

```
public void run() {

    while (socket != null) {
        try {
            int dataLength = din.readInt();
            byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
            din.readFully(data, 0, dataLength);
            Event e = ef.getEvent(data);
            node.onEvent(e);    
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());
            break;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage()) ;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you have a large number of threads sending data to the same socket? NB Your receive code should catch `EOFException` separately, and not log it: it's normal. You should also add a `BufferedOutputStream` between the `DataOutputStream` and the socket output stream. [Otherwise the `flush()` is redundant.]

Comment: Clients are sending data back and forth to each other. It's possible at any given time, for example, Client A and Client B are both sending data to Client C.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it. You are correct, the output stream is tied to the socket, dunno know why I was thinking that!  That helps actually, and may be where I'm messing up. I actually have two threads running for each client, one for sending and one for receiving. The receiving thread may need to forward the message on, so at this point it's possible Client A's sending and receiving are both trying to send using the same output stream...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that one of your calls to the output stream throws an exception and `sendLock.unlock()` is never called. All the other threads will be left waiting forever.

Check your logs to see if one of the threads throws an exception. In your code I would use a try-catch-finally block instead of throwing IOException. This guarantees, even if something bad happens, the lock will be released so other threads can keep working.

```
public void sendData(byte[] dataToSend) throws IOException {
    try {
        sendLock.lock();

        int dataLength = dataToSend.length;
        dout.writeInt(dataLength);
        dout.write(dataToSend, 0, dataLength);
        dout.flush();
    }
    finally {
         sendLock.unlock();
    }
}
```